# I have an error with unused variable warning

Tags: c++

I have an warning in my copy constructor.

Basically I had an error in copy assignment and I solved it, but then a warning (which is treated as an error) pops up in my copy constructor.

```
IntList::IntList(const IntList& cpy){
  head = 0; 
  tail = 0;
  for(IntNode* i = cpy.head; i != 0; i = i->next){
    push_back(i->data);
  }
  IntList* obj1;
  IntList* obj2 = obj1;
}

IntList& IntList::operator=(const IntList& rhs){
  head = 0;
  tail = 0;
  for(IntNode* i = rhs.head; i != 0; i = i -> next){
    push_back(i->data);
  }
  IntList* obj1;
  IntList* obj2 = obj1;
  return *obj2;
}
```

I think it's used, because i assigned obj2 with obj1(but why is it regarded to be unused???)

i tried this but still not being solved

```
IntList* obj1;
IntList* obj2;
obj2 = obj1;
```

Comment: It is *assigned*, but its value is not *used* afterwards, so the assignment is literally useless.

Comment: Please include the actual compiler warning or this question is likely to be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These statements

```
IntList* obj1;
IntList* obj2 = obj1;
```

do not make any sense. Remove them.

Take into account that the copy assignment operator

```
IntList& IntList::operator=(const IntList& rhs){
  head = 0;
  tail = 0;
  for(IntNode* i = rhs.head; i != 0; i = i -> next){
    push_back(i->data);
  }
  IntList* obj1;
  IntList* obj2 = obj1;
  return *obj2;
}
```

is invalid. It does not free all previously allocated memory for the list. And it shall return reference to it self. So the last statement shall be

```
return *this;
```

The operator can look the following way

```
IntList & IntList::operator =( const IntList &rhs )
{
    while ( head )
    {
        IntNode *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }

    tail = head;

    for ( IntNode* i = rhs.head; i != 0; i = i -> next )
    {
        push_back( i->data );
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the two lines containing `obj1` and `obj2` in the assignment operator function with `return *this;`. The two lines containing `obj1` and `obj2` are not needed in the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The following has no use in the code. It is pointless.

```
IntList* obj1; 
IntList* obj2 = obj1;
```

Also, it looks to be that you're copying the list but you're not actually assigning the head node to some pointer. So when the function is over, you lose the copied list.

Comment: @Vivek  And what does the function push_back do? What do you think?:)

Comment: He hasn't shown what it does. As far as we know, all it could be doing is adding the data value to the data property of the node.

Comment: Correction: Node i

Comment: Well if the function adds nodes what happens with the head and tail?:)

Comment: That's what I'm saying. The head node is not being equated to the list. Am I wrong?

Comment: got it. push_back is probably setting the head and tail values.